# Change socket timeout for grails 3 RestBuilder client post request

Tags: grails

I have a grails 3 application using the `grails.plugins.rest.client` plugin to make calls to another API.The api performs some actions and responds in 40 to 50 seconds. The grails application timeout and returns a server error in 30 seconds. How can I **change the timeout to wait for a response 60 seconds**. My code is as follows:

```
import grails.plugins.rest.client.RestBuilder
import grails.plugins.rest.client.RestResponse

private RestBuilder rest = new RestBuilder()

RestResponse resp = rest.post(url) {
            header 'Accept', "application/json"
            json(data)
        }
// more code
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to increase the socket timeout the grails rest client supports two options.

- connectionTimeout
- readTimeout

These options are to be set on the **RestBuilder** when it is instantiated. You **cannot** change this for request
types which is a shame.

To set them, you can use the below format. But bear in mind that it requires a change to the code and rebuilding the war file.

```
    private RestBuilder rest = new RestBuilder(readTimeout: 180000, proxy: Proxy.NO_PROXY)
```

> 180000 = 180 seconds = 3 mins readTimeout

You can also set the `connectionTimeout` here, but most likely you will be limited by the `connectiontimeOut` property on the servlet container like Tomcat or CDN like cloudfront or cloudflare.

If you are also using tomcat, you may need to increase the async timeout like in the below example in  directive. Hope this helps others looking to solve the same problem.

```
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               asyncTimeout="60000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
```